# fieldset Legend custom style

Tags: html, css

I am working on the HTML form. Form includes fieldsets and legends.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/PYmGG/).

I want to display answer choices in front of legends. What style should be given to legend or fieldset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PYmGG/3/

Relevant CSS

```
legend, label, input { float: left }

fieldset { height: auto; overflow: hidden; 
           /* float clearing applied to fieldsets */ }
```

You may want to give some `margin-right` to `legend` element and give some space between `fieldsets` applying a `margin-bottom` on them

Comment: Great solution!
I would set display: block; width: Xpx to the label element to place the answers at the same position.

Comment: you could assign a `min-width` to legend element